# How do you create login and register pages without having to connect to backend (ReactJS + Redux)?

Tags: javascript, redux, reactjs

I am attempting to create a login and a register page using ReactJS + Redux. Currently once a user registers, the user's object with the registered info are stored inside an array:

```
 const userDataReducer = function(users = [], action){
  switch (action.type){
    case 'ADD_USER':
      return[{
        username: action.username,
        email: action.email,
        name: action.name,
        password: action.password
      }, ...users]
```

and once it is registered, the user enters the username and password in the login form and submits it:

verifyLoginUser(){
    event.preventDefault()

```
if(this.props.actions.verifyUser(this.props.loginUser.username, this.props.loginUser.password)){
  console.log('LOGGED IN')
} else {
  console.log('NOT LOGGED IN')
}
```

}

and inside userDataReducer.js verifies with the following:

```
case 'VERIFY_USER':
  let isVerified = false;
  users.forEach((user)=> {
    if(user.username === action.username && user.password ===  action.password){
      isVerified = true;
      return false;
    }
  });
  return isVerified;
```

The actions are:

```
  addUser: function(username, email, name, password) {
    return {
      type: 'ADD_USER',
      username: username,
      email: email,
      name: name,
      password: password
    }
  },

  verifyUser: function(username, password){
    return {
      type: 'VERIFY_USER',
      username: username,
      password: password
    }
  }
```

Currently, if a user tries to login and click submit, it just continues to return 'LOGGED IN' in any cases.

In ReactJS + Redux, is this the correct way to go about creating Login and Register pages just via front-end? Any guidance or insight would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

"Login and register just via front-end" probably goes against everything in the book, so if you are looking for implementing good practices, that might be a good place to start - https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-do-client-side-only-javascript-authentication

Regarding React and Redux, your code looks good. I would just point out 2 things about your actions:

1. It is a good practice for actions to contain a `payload` property - https://github.com/acdlite/flux-standard-action
2. `VERIFY_USER` is only reading data, not storing. So you don't actually need an action there, nor does the code need to live in a reducer. That code should probably be a method of your authentication component.